# differential equation and sketching of solution graph

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve an exercise taken from a book. It is no homework, but i could lie to you so you probably dont care about this much.

**The exercise:**
Consider the following differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x+sin(y)$.

Show that the second derivative of every solution satisfies: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1+x*cos(y)+0.5*sin(2y)$

**My thoughts:**
Since there is no explicit/implicit solution given i dont know how to start the proof. Could someone shed light onto this or give me a hint that could lead to a basic approach?

Comment: You know $\frac{dy}{dx}$. How do you find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** When calculating the second derivative, implicit differentiation would yield a $\frac{dy}{dx}$ term, which you can replace with the first equation.

Just do it.

Comment: You are saying that i can implicitly differentiate the first equation, then plug it in for $frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in the second equation. Thanks!